# How to rotate arrow/chevron/caret on active nested accordion section

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I trying to rotate an icon on the active section of a nested Materialize JS accordion menu.

The icons also need to show the active nested section.

Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/adburns/zLw256av/10/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  $(function() {
    var path = "some-folder/some-link4.aspx";
    var selector = 'a[href="' + path + '"]';
    var links = $(selector);
    links.each(function(index) {
      var link = $(this).addClass('deep-orange-text');
      var parent = link.closest('ul.collapsible > li');
      parent.addClass('active');
      var grandparent = parent.parents('ul.collapsible > li');
      grandparent.addClass('active');
    });


    // Collapsible doesn't have a refresh. 
    // Just instantiate it again in order to work.
    $('.collapsible').collapsible()
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

.collapsible-header {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.right {
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">



<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">WS <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <ul class="collapsible">
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header">WS M <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link1.aspx>Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link2.aspx>Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link3.aspx>Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header">WS P <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link4.aspx>Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link5.aspx>Link 5</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link6.aspx>Link 6</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header">WS S <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">HS <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">SS <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking for something like https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/vMZGxM but with nested sections, as in my Fiddle.

Comment: Please, show us what have you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: @Burns check the answer

Answer (score 1):

just put below css in your css location.

```css
.collapsible-header > i {
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.active>.collapsible-header>i {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

You can check your snippet in my answer with your solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  $(function() {
    var path = "some-folder/some-link4.aspx";
    var selector = 'a[href="' + path + '"]';
    var links = $(selector);
    links.each(function(index) {
      var link = $(this).addClass('deep-orange-text');
      var parent = link.closest('ul.collapsible > li');
      parent.addClass('active');
      var grandparent = parent.parents('ul.collapsible > li');
      grandparent.addClass('active');
    });


    // Collapsible doesn't have a refresh. 
    // Just instantiate it again in order to work.
    $('.collapsible').collapsible()
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

.collapsible-header {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.right {
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.collapsible-header > i {
     transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.active>.collapsible-header>i {
     transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">



<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">WS <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <ul class="collapsible">
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header">WS M <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link1.aspx>Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link2.aspx>Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link3.aspx>Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header">WS P <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link4.aspx>Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link5.aspx>Link 5</a></li>
              <li><a href=some-folder/some-link6.aspx>Link 6</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header">WS S <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">HS <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">SS <i class="material-icons right">expand_more</i></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks, can't believe it was that simple.  Not sure how missed that :( thank you,

Comment: @Burns Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer solved your question, be sure to upvote it and also click the checkmark to "accept" it. And do the same with your other questions that were answered. This helps visitors find quality answers, and the people who answer your questions always appreciate the reputation points. Thanks!